# is it possible to Lazy-load a Module/component without routing in angular 5.2?

Tags: angular

is it possible to Lazy-load a Module/component **without routing** in angular 5 ? if Yes how?

I saw some stack overflow topics about, but no definitive answer !!!, like :

1. Is there a pre built in feature in Angular ?
2. If there is a go around solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: why would you want to not use lazy loading without routing? The lazy loaded modules have their own routing and this is mentioned in the docs as well.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: take a look to this [link](https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093) It's look like you're looking for

Comment: This lybrary lazy load component without routing https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazy-load-component